# In CSS how to make a child to depend on the size of it's container, which depends on that child's sibling?

Tags: css

Let's say i have

```
<container> 
  <A>
  <B>
</container>
```

How do i make the size of the container to depend on the size of element A, but independent from the size of B? So that the size of B depends on the size of the container which depends on the size of A? So that A would define the size of everything

Comment: `width:0;min-width:100%` for `<B>` And make the `<container>` an inline level element

Comment: By size do you mention about the width alone or the height too??

Comment: @Mithunraj i mean only width, but does it make a difference?

Comment: updated the duplicate list with more relevant duplicates